# creating an object in ternary operator from query result

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to create objects to return to front end from data I got from database because the response doesnt contain ALL fields of entity and I also add this [NotMapped] propety `AmountOfTenants = t.Apartment.Tenants.Count(),` to the response.

If I remove ternary operator here `t.ApartmentId != null ?` and just create `new Apartment` every time, then, when a Tenant doesnt have any related Apartmetn to him, then my json response contains Tenant with an Apartment object inside of him, where all values are 0/null, thats why i need ternary, to set Apartment to null if Tenant's `ApartmentId` is null.
Without ternary it works, but i get that apartment with 0/null values and when i add ternary operator i get this error:
`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression'.`
Please help

```
List<Tenant> tenants = await _context.Tenants.Include(tenant => tenant.Apartment.House)
                .Select(t => new Tenant
                {
                    Id = t.Id,
                    FirstName = t.FirstName,
                    LastName = t.LastName,
                    PersonalCode = t.PersonalCode,
                    Birthday = t.Birthday,
                    PhoneNumber = t.PhoneNumber,
                    Email = t.Email,
                    ApartmentId = t.ApartmentId,
                    Apartment = t.ApartmentId != null ? new Apartment
                    {
                        Id = t.Apartment.Id,
                        Number = t.Apartment.Number,
                        Floor = t.Apartment.Floor,
                        AmountOfTenants = t.Apartment.Tenants.Count(),
                        AmountOfRooms = t.Apartment.AmountOfRooms,
                        TotalArea = t.Apartment.TotalArea,
                        AvailableArea = t.Apartment.AvailableArea,
                        HouseId = t.Apartment.HouseId,
                        House = t.Apartment.House
                    } : null
                }).ToListAsync();
```

----------------------------------------------EDIT
someone asked for Tenant entity:

```
namespace RestApi.Models
{
    public class Tenant
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PersonalCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public long? ApartmentId { get; set; }
        public Apartment? Apartment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

--------------------------EDIT
someone asked for Apartment class:

```
namespace RestApi.Models
{
    public class Apartment
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int Floor { get; set; }
        public int AmountOfRooms { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int AmountOfTenants { get; set; }
        public int TotalArea{ get; set; }
        public int AvailableArea { get; set; }
        public long? HouseId { get; set; }
        public House House { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
    }
}
```

------------------------------ EDIT
I got a friend to check something similar on his machine:

```
var tenants = await context.Tenants
  .Include(t => t.Apartment).ThenInclude(a => a.House)
  .Include(t => t.Apartment).ThenInclude(a => a.Tenants)
  .Select(t => new Tenant
  {
    Id = t.Id,
    //etc...
    Apartment = t.ApartmentId != null ? new Apartment
    {
      Id = t.Apartment.Id,
      NumberOfTenants = t.Apartment.Tenants.Count(),
      //etc...
    } : null
  }).ToListAsync();
```

on his machine this `new` statement inside another `new` statement works and gives no error

Comment: Can you share your Tenant class?

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but why are you even using the `Select`?

Comment: to add `t.Apartment.Tenants.Count(),` and not maintain this column in db, not add+1 or remove-1 when i add a tenant to apartment and to cherry pick properties of Apartment to return to front end

Comment: can I see your apartment class? I have and idea that might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using this, which should eliminate the need to use the `NotMapped` annotation and you wouldn't need to use the select at that point either.

```
    public class Apartment
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int Floor { get; set; }
        public int AmountOfRooms { get; set; }
        public int AmountOfTenants { get { return this.Tenants != null ? this.Tenants.Count : 0; } }
        public int TotalArea { get; set; }
        public int AvailableArea { get; set; }
        public long? HouseId { get; set; }
        public House House { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
    }
```

**New Query**

```
List<Tenant> tenants = await _context.Tenants.Include(tenant => tenant.Apartment).ThenInclude(a => a.House).ToListAsync();
```

***Edit***

As for an explanation of the error you are getting. It is basically saying that it can't make a `new` expression inside of a `new` expression (i.e. creating a `new Apartment` inside of a `new Tenant`)

Comment: changing the class to your version and using your query gives this error
``A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.`` as expected. cause when querying for Tenants will Query Apartments, which have Tenants and so forth

Comment: Ah, `System.Text.Json` has a limitation for the reference loop handling. As in it does not support it. In order for my code to work you would have to use something like `Newtonsoft.Json`, that supports reference loop handling.

Comment: thanks. added Newtonsoft, now it works, but returns the empty array instead of infinite loop, so kind of a trash unused values being sent over every time.
If you have an idea about the error in the original post - would be nice to know what it is.
Gonna use your solution for now though. thanks

Comment: Oh, I know what the error above is. I will edit my answer for you.

Comment: Can you check last edit ? What exactly prevents `new` inside another `new` ? My friend says it works for him. Is it some dependency that doesn't let me do it ? He's using SqlServer though for his test and in my app im using InMemoryDatabase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215689/discussion-between-patrick-mcvay-and-caribbean).

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption about your Apartments class so correct me if I go astray here.
Assumption : A tenant can only have one apartment and an apartment can have multiple tenants.

With that being said you tenant class just needs to reference an Apartment object. The Apartment ID is contained in Apartment object so you're really storing that data twice. If you're looking to add an new tenant to an apartment you don't need the select statement. You might want to do a bullet point summary to clarify your intentions if there is more to this.  If you're looking to include all objects within the Tenant class(data from other tables) you can consider lazy loading if your application permits.

```
public class Tenant
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; } //Primary Key
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PersonalCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    //public long? ApartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Apartment Apartment { get; set; }
}

public class Apartment
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ApartmentID { get; set; } //Primary Key
    public virtual List<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
}
 public class appStuff
{
    void AddStuff()
    {
        var myContext = new _context();
        Apartment apartment = myContext.Find(Predicate4YourApartment());
        var ten = new Tenant
        {
            Birthday = DateAndTime.Now,
            Apartment = apartment,
            FirstName = "John" //add the rest.
        };

        myContext.TenantsTable.Add(ten);

        //This will add the Tenant to the Tenants table and the apartment to the Apartments table if you create a new one 
        //instead of finding an existing one like shown above
        myContext.SaveChanges(); 

    }
 void GetStuff()
    {
        var myContext = new _context();
        var myTenant = myContext.TenantsTable.Where(x => x.Apartment.ApartmentID == "DesiredID");
    }
}

public class _context : DbContext
{
    public _context() : base()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    }
}
```